# Get location of href from page generated via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a curl script that make a call and print result:

```
<div class="myClass">
<h3><a href="http://www.mysite.net/product-id"  class="link " title="xxx">Title of link</a>
</h3>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init("mysite.net/xxx/xxx/xxx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, ' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0' );
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $html;
```

The page automatically must print only the URLs between this div

How is the best way to do that? Javascript?

Comment: Hi there, do you mean that this is the contents that you read from within PHP using Curl and you want to render the URLs on your page?

Comment: Yes the content is large HTML code, but I need that it print only the href into the div that have class "myClass"

Comment: Can you show your PHP please, it will make things more clear.

Comment: Ok:
`$ch = curl_init("http://www.mysite.net/xxx/xxx/xxx");`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);`
`curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, ' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0' );`
`$html = curl_exec($ch);`
`curl_close($ch);`
`    `
`echo $html;`

Comment: And that code sits within `<div class="myClass">`? Or is that returned by Curl?

Comment: is contained in the code that curl returns

Comment: So.... you want to keep that `div` but strip the `h3` and `a` tags and just leave the URL?

Comment: No, I must print only the url contained in that `<div class="myClass">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `pre_match` in php page for example

```
if ( preg_match("'<a.*?href=\"(http[s]*://[^>\"]*?)\"[^>]*?>(.*?)</a>'si",$html ,$m) )
{
   echo "the link is =>".$m[1];
}

//or to get between <div class="myClass">
if ( preg_match('/<div class="myClass">(.*)<\/div>/is',$html,$m) )
{
   echo "<br />found this =>".$m[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro.
I have modified it with preg_match_all and with foreach print out all url